# Overflow: Hidden is croping the text and button in Header/ Banner

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Let me preface my question with this: I'm a total beginner.I'm really sorry for the long code snippets and code.

I'm trying to make this "Header"/ "Banner" (see code) show everything inside them but by using "overflow: hidden", elements inside the "Header"/ "Banner" get cropped out.

Example: If I try to move my Button outside of these parameters that I obviously have set (without me knowing) it gets cropped out. I want to have more space between the text lines and the button without it getting cropped.
I just don't know to make it all visible even if I change the position of the button, like in the example.

I am at a loss, I tried changing every variable possible. This is probably obvious but I just can't seem to make my idea work.

```css
/* default margin and padding for all elements */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* decrese font size of the HTML file */
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* Creating & styling hamburger menu */
.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 3rem;
    z-index: 200;
    /* create lines for menu */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Costomize header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
/*Header: parent of banner--> set position to relative */
    position: relative;
}


/* Banner styling */
.banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    perspective: 300rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styling h1 & h2 for banner */
.banner h1 {
    font-family: Lobster Two, serif;
    font-size: 8rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: darkred;
    text-shadow: 0.3rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;

}

.banner1 h2 {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;
}

/* Paragraph styling for banner*/
.banner p {
    font-family: 'Mulish', serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-size: 700;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;
}

/* Styling Button */
.banner .btn button {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: darkred;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .9s forwards;
}

/* Banner animation */
@keyframes moveBanner {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(40rem) rotateY(-20deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Menu style with 3 lines -> hamburger -->
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="images/houses.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>Red String</h1>
                    <div class="banner1">
                        <h2>Blah blah blah</h2>
                    </div>
                <p>I dont know what i should put here.</p>
                <div class="btn">
                    <button>Calculate now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Being a beginner, have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3124333) :p

Comment: "I want to have more space between the text lines and the button without it getting cropped." How about adding some margin-bottom on the text above the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the context in which you need to have overflow hidden, usually you'd have a set height to enforce clipping? If you want to make sure the banner doesn't go outside the `100vh` set on the `header` then you should put the `overflow:hidden` there. However it will always clip anything that goes outside its set height because that's what it's for..

But if you give your banner/parent container some padding, there will always be space around your child elements, including buttons to allow for effects like drop shadows etc. Then you can also move your button where-ever.

```css
/* default margin and padding for all elements */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* decrese font size of the HTML file */
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* Creating & styling hamburger menu */
.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 3rem;
    z-index: 200;
    /* create lines for menu */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Costomize header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
/*Header: parent of banner--> set position to relative */
    position: relative;
}


/* Banner styling */
.banner {
background:#ccc;
/*just plopped this bg color in so we can see what's happening better */
padding:5%;
/*give your contents room to breathe with padding */
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    perspective: 300rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styling h1 & h2 for banner */
.banner h1 {
    font-family: Lobster Two, serif;
    font-size: 8rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: darkred;
    text-shadow: 0.3rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;

}

.banner1 h2 {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;
}

/* Paragraph styling for banner*/
.banner p {
    font-family: 'Mulish', serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-size: 700;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .7s forwards;
}

/* Styling Button */
.banner .btn button {
    margin-top:2rem;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: darkred;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: moveBanner 1s .9s forwards;
}

/* Banner animation */
@keyframes moveBanner {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(40rem) rotateY(-20deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Menu style with 3 lines -> hamburger -->
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="images/houses.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>Red String</h1>
                    <div class="banner1">
                        <h2>Blah blah blah</h2>
                    </div>
                <p>I dont know what i should put here.</p>
                <div class="btn">
                    <button>Calculate now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I completely forgot about checking the size of my banner with the browser's dev tools (rookie mistake). I added "height" to the banner to make the visible parameter bigger. That solved my problem. I'll try the padding as an alternative. The past couple of days of struggling now seem unnecessary. To my defense, the last couple of days were rough... live and learn.